# Can I have a transparent background in my desktop application made with openfl

Tags: windows, macos, haxe, openfl

I'd like to know if there is a way to set the main Application window background to be transparent so that you can see all the other applications behind it when building for macOS and Windows using openfl

My project file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project>

    <meta title="DeskClock" package="com.sample.deskclock" version="1.0.0" company="Company Name" />
    <app main="Main" path="Export" file="DeskClock" />
    <window hardware="true" allow-shaders="true" require-shaders="true" depth-buffer="false" stencil-buffer="false" />

    <window 
    background="0x00000000" 
    fullscreen="false" 
    resizable="false" 
    borderless="true" 
    vsync="true"/>

    <window always-on-top="true" /> 

    <source path="Source" />

    <haxelib name="openfl" />

    <assets path="Assets" rename="assets" />

</project>
```

and my main file looks like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if your targeting Air Desktop, however there is a performance hit and not sure if you can use Stage GPU stuff.
I'm not sure about the windows cpp target.

Comment: You are correct about the Air target. I used to do AIR development. I'd rather find a way to do it with native cpp.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing fine, the simplest to use transparency looks like this:

```
<window background="null" color-depth="32" />
```

OpenFL uses 16-bit color on OpenGL by default, with no alpha, so `color-depth` is important to allow a transparent background.

This will work on HTML5, I tested on Linux, and I don't believe the X11 window created by SDL is transparent, even when the borders are hidden. It is possible that there may need to be more work on creating the native window, depending on the platform. macOS or Windows might work with the above.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work on macOS or Windows. Thanks for the heads-up up on the setting. Is there anything I can do to contribute to getting this feature added to the Native X11 windows? I really think this would open up so many possibilities of apps I'd like to build. I want to build a handful of suttle widget type desktop apps for windows and mac and I'd like to use haxe / openfl to do it. I think having transparent windows would really make things look so much better.

Comment: I believe our renderer and how we initialize our GL context should support transparency, but I could be mistaken. I think we're down to a lower-level now, of possibly trying custom window creation code, and `SDL_CreateWindowFrom`